# certbot: Could not find a usable 'nginx' binary

Tags: certbot

I am on centos7, using certbot 1.17.0 to execute `certbot --nginx`

Then got an error

```
The nginx plugin is not working; there may be problems with your existing configuration.
The error was: NoInstallationError("Could not find a usable 'nginx' binary. Ensure nginx exists, the binary is executable, and your PATH is set correctly.")
```

My nginx is installed in another directory, can I specify the directory where nginx is located when running certbot

```sh
# nginx -t
nginx: the configuration file /usr/local/nginx/conf/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /usr/local/nginx/conf/nginx.conf test is successful
```

Comment: I now use `certbot certonly -d xxx.com` to generate the certificate, manually configure the certificate in my nginx

Answer (score 0):

The reason could be that the cron path is'nt the same as your shell path.

You can check in your `/etc/cron.d` folder.

More information can be found [here](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/failed-to-autorenew-from-cron-could-not-find-a-usable-nginx-binary/102696)